# c# remove strings from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How can i remove any strings from an array and have only integers instead

```
string[] result = col["uncheckedFoods"].Split(',');
```

**I have**

```
[0] = on;      // remove this string
[1] = 22;
[2] = 23;
[3] = off;      // remove this string
[4] = 24;
```

**I want**

```
[0] = 22;
[1] = 23;
[2] = 24;
```

**I tried**

```
var commaSepratedID = string.Join(",", result);

var data = Regex.Replace(commaSepratedID, "[^,0-9]+", string.Empty);
```

But there is a comma before first element, is there any better way to remove strings ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This selects all strings which can be parsed as `int`

```
string[] result = new string[5];
result[0] = "on";      // remove this string
result[1] = "22";
result[2] = "23";
result[3] = "off";      // remove this string
result[4] = "24";
int temp;
result = result.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out temp)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't know much about this so is this better than regex method in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Thank you, works fine , SO system is designed to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @Sean83 in this case it should be faster compared to RegEx

Answer (score 0):

To also support `double` I would do something like this:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(string input, NumberStyles numberStyle)
{
   double temp;
   return Double.TryParse(input, numberStyle, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out temp);
}
```

and then

```
string[] result = new string[] {"abc", "10", "4.1" };
var res = result.Where(b => IsNumeric(b, NumberStyles.Number));
// res contains "10" and "4.1"
```

Comment: I only need integers from an array, this answers might help someone in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  dynamic[] result = { "23", "RT", "43", "67", "gf", "43" };

                for(int i=1;i<=result.Count();i++)
                {
                    var getvalue = result[i];
                    int num;
                    if (int.TryParse(getvalue, out num))
                    {
                        Console.Write(num);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        // It's a number!
                    }
                }
```

Comment: why a dynamic type? what is the benefit of your answer over the accepted one?

Comment: dynamic use when values data type  are not clean but in this case if we use String array then result will be same

Comment: Never use `dynamic` if not needed. In this case, you have to use `string` (even if it is working with dynamic...)

Comment: ok thanks, but when i have no idea which type of data will come dynamically in arrray then what should i do?

Comment: if you have any idea  or example related to this , then it will be very helpful for me